# Google Maps API v3 - new browser key, still REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I've enabled the Google Maps v3 (and v2) services in the API console and then generated a browser key.

I just swapped a `maps.google.com/geo?q=` URL for the below URL (example):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&key=newbrowserkeyfromconsole&address=ALE+BILSERVICE,ALVANGEN,Sweden
```

***It is called with 1600 HTTPGET requests in one run, but now it doesn't even work when pasting 1 URL in a browser!***

**EDIT: I wrote that it runs once per day, but that is false. Fixed street addresses don't suddenly switch GPS coordinates. ;)**

I looked at several similar threads, where generating a new browser key in the API console seemed to work. But not for me. I'm running this from "whatever client ip", so I left the url filter box empty when generating it, and get "Any referrer allowed", so it seems OK.

If I remove the key, I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

Please advise.

Comment: @Jordan: Why was the Google tag removed? The API Console support advised me to add it, so that Google employees could find the tagged questions and answer promptly. SO disallows this, but keeps the tag?

Comment: I removed the google-bigquery tag, because this wasn't a bigquery question.

Comment: But from what I gathered this is the only way to get support from a Google technician. Is there some other way to get a Google technician to look at why the keys don't work? Open a ticket? Pay for support? It's either a Google API or account bug, since everything in the API Console looks hunky-dory. 0 request have been used of the quota.

Comment: Google's support link on the maps API page was incorrect and landed me on the bigquery support page. The google-maps-api-3 tag should be monitored fine, although they haven't responded to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently, the Google API Console ***cannot generate working API v3 browser keys*** for geocoding use at all, whether used via a JSON output URL or Javascript. This has been the case for at least the past 3 days.

[***Just as for Google Places a few months ago.***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060563/google-places-api-request-denied?rq=1)

All you can do is ignore the error code 610, REQUEST_DENIED, and erroneous alerts, and wait for Google to fix it.

I'll be happy to change the accepted answer to one that describes how to contact Google about your Google Developer account, raise a ticket, register/pay for support, or similar.