# Android Google Place API Error Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, placeautocompletefragment

Hello I am facing the Google Place API Error

```
Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}
```

According to Google new policy "Deprecation notice: Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android"

> Notice: The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019. A new version of the Places SDK for Android is now available. We recommend updating to the new version as soon as possible. For details, see the migration guide.
>   [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)

My Android Code

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBQzpD8_pXzixi7_bUfQVMgvfF0QBxinM0"/>

 placeAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES).build();

    placeAutocompleteFragment.setFilter(autocompleteFilter);

    placeAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),place.getName().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            System.out.println("apierror   "+status.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),status.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

LogCat

> 2019-03-15 11:56:53.778 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid I/System.out: apierror   Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.814 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@1326f91[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.814 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@1326f91[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 543796078080}
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.814 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/SEM_CLIP_SemClipboardManager: isCocktailBarDisplayed : false
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.815 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@7b271e1 nm : com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid ic=null
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.815 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.819 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=68
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.825 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.830 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=70
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.831 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{9034b1d V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.841 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.875 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[115,1980][1324,2304] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 543267962880} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.875 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 543267962880} hwInitialized=true
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.878 17418-17433/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1209x324]-format:1
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.878 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
>   2019-03-15 11:56:53.898 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@1326f91[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
>   2019-03-15 11:56:55.825 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
>   2019-03-15 11:56:55.826 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/ViewRootImpl@eace7f4[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
>   2019-03-15 11:56:55.846 17418-17418/com.manish.velmurugan.googleautocompleteplacesandroid D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=70

>

> what is the alternative to achive this task "Place Autocomplete"
>
> This question is not duplicate [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449649/android-google-places-api-getautocompletepredictions-returns-status-places-api) becouse this question is asked 3 year before for now.

Comment: have you tried the same solution which is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449649/android-google-places-api-getautocompletepredictions-returns-status-places-api

Comment: @NoumanCh Yes but google api policy is change now so that the solutions are not working Please upvote this question so i can get solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827206/how-to-resolve-places-api-for-android-does-not-seem-to-be-enabled-for-your-app)

Comment: @VirajPatel is i integrated the code give for sample but this error is showing "E/Places: Error while autocompleting: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"   please not that my billing account is enable for the key.

Answer (score 2):

Ill solve the problem regarding google place API, i am created the GitHub Public Repository to simulate the the Google Place API

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ManishAndroidIos/Master-Google-Place-API.git)